# In django, views here i ran into a problem that my varible called created{"created" is not accessed} so plz see my code and tell me answer

Tags: django, variables, django-models, django-templates

I am just showing my views.py because problem is just here after at third line after order.

def cart(request):

```
customer = request.user.customer
order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
items = order.orderitem_set.all()

  
context = {'items':items}
return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
```

Here ,i also dont know that why we use a word like created, what is its purpose.Thanks.

> Blockquote

Comment: Are you getting an error or are you just asking what the purpose of the variable `created` is? Have you looked at the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create?

Comment: Bro,i am getting error that the [created] seen  dull and it say that  {(variable) created: bool
"created" is not accessed}.So what i Do now.

Comment: It's your IDE complaining about an unused variable? Replace `created` with `_` and you shouldn't get the warning anymore I think, it's common to use `_` as a variable name for an un-used variable in Python

Comment: Thanks Bro, Now it will work same as created works?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you use `_` as the variable name instead of `created` it will still contain the same value just with a different name, so in that way it still "works the same"

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in third line.
You did:

```
items = order.orderitem_set.all()
```

when it should be:

```
items =**O**rder.orderitem_set.all()
```